# Sort dictionary of dictionaries in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries (for countries) as below:

```
US =     {
    areaCode = 1;
    code = US;
    name = "United States";
};
UY =     {
    areaCode = 598;
    code = UY;
    name = Uruguay;
};
UZ =     {
    areaCode = 998;
    code = UZ;
    name = Uzbekistan;
};
```

How could I sort it with "name" key of inner dictionary ?

More Explanation and Edit:
I created this dictionary (key/value system) as below:

```
NSString *countriesPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"countries" ofType:@"csv"];
NSMutableDictionary *countries = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:countriesPath usedEncoding:nil error:nil];
rows = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
for (NSString *row in rows){
    NSArray* columns = [row componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSDictionary *CountryRowData = @{
                                     @"code":     columns[0],
                                     @"name":     columns[1],
                                     @"areaCode": columns[2]
                                     };
    countries[columns[0]]= CountryRowData;
}
_countries = countries;
```

Comment: You don't sort a `NSDictionary`. Its a KEY/VALUE system, not a index one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't sort a dictionary—it's an *unordered* collection. You can sort an array of keys, though:

```
NSDictionary *countries;

NSArray *sortedKeys = [[countries allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *key1, NSString *key2) {
    return [countries[key1][@"name"] compare:countries[key2][@"name"]];
}];

// sortedKeys is now ( US, UY, UZ )
```

Comment: thanks, but how to put it to previous unordered collection? It's an array now. It seems I need one fetch loop to this array again, yea?

Comment: @novinfard I don't understand your question, sorry.